# Fiware QuantumLeap Error when receiving subscription message "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'"

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, cratedb

Fiware QuantumLeap throws an Error when receiving a subscription message from Orion-LD:

```
time=2023-04-10 09:05:48.876 | level=ERROR | corr=None | from=172.24.0.8 | srv=None | subserv=None | op=log_exception | comp=server.wsgi | msg=Exception on /v2/notify [POST] | payload=[{'id': 'urn:ngsi-ld:Wasserstandsensor:001', 'type': 'Wasserstandsensor', 'observation': 494}] | thread=139933603838752  | process=34
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877623243Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877631202Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877634240Z     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877636776Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877639211Z     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877641530Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877643934Z     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877646229Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877648604Z     raise value
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877651288Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877654042Z     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877656649Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877659054Z     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877670344Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 48, in wrapper
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877673234Z     response = function(request)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877675489Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/uri_parsing.py", line 144, in wrapper
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877677872Z     response = function(request)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877680107Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 184, in wrapper
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877682499Z     response = function(request)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877684732Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 384, in wrapper
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877687106Z     return function(request)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877689337Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 121, in wrapper
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877691704Z     return function(**kwargs)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877693942Z   File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/reporter/reporter.py", line 154, in notify
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877696385Z     error = _validate_payload(entity)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877698631Z   File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/reporter/reporter.py", line 103, in _validate_payload
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877701580Z     if not has_value(payload, attr):
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877703946Z   File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/reporter/reporter.py", line 61, in has_value
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877706381Z     attr_value = attr.get('value', None)
2023-04-10T09:05:48.877708808Z AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Log from Orion-LD:

```
TMP@09:05:48  httpRequestSend.cpp[564]: Sending message 6 to HTTP server: sending message of 713 bytes to HTTP server
2023-04-10T09:05:48.878008552Z INFO@09:05:48  httpRequestSend.cpp[587]: Notification Successfully Sent to http://fiware-quantumleap:8668/v2/notify?subscriptionId=urn:ngsi-ld:Subscription:25b0913a-d77e-11ed-a74b-0242ac180008
```

Subscription Message with Status 201:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
--header 'fiware-service: waterlevel' \
--header 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
--data-raw '{
    "description": "Notify STH-Comet of all Wasserstand changes",
    "type": "Subscription",
    "entities": [{"type": "Wasserstandsensor"}],
    "watchedAttributes": ["observation"],
    "notification": {
        "endpoint": {
            "uri": "http://fiware-quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
        },
        "attributes": ["observation"]
    },
    "@context": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld"
}'
```

docker-compose:

```
  crate-db:
    image: crate:4.1.4
    hostname: crate-db
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "4300:4300"
    command:
      crate  -Cauth.host_based.enabled=false  -Ccluster.name=democluster
      -Chttp.cors.enabled=true -Chttp.cors.allow-origin="*"
    environment:
      - CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=2g

  fiware-quantumleap:
    image: smartsdk/quantumleap
    hostname: fiware-quantumleap
    ports:
      - "8668:8668"
    depends_on:
      - crate-db
    environment:
      - CRATE_HOST=crate-db
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks!

I need the @context because the entity names are FQN and they can't be found otherwise.